# Resizing of images (increase the size of the screen shot) in microsoft word automatically

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I need to resize (increase the size) the multiple screesn shots in word document in a single click.

i have a macro with me. Following is the one..

```
Sub ResizePics()
 Dim shp As Word.Shape
 Dim ishp As Word.InlineShape
 If Word.Selection.Type <> wdSelectionInlineShape And _
 Word.Selection.Type <> wdSelectionShape Then
 Exit Sub
 End If
 If Word.Selection.Type = wdSelectionInlineShape Then
 Set ishp = Word.Selection.Range.InlineShapes(1)
 ishp.LockAspectRatio = False
 ishp.Height = InchesToPoints(1.78)
 ishp.Width = InchesToPoints(3.17)
 Else
 If Word.Selection.Type = wdSelectionShape Then
 Set shp = Word.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
 shp.LockAspectRatio = False
 shp.Height = InchesToPoints(1.78)
 shp.Width = InchesToPoints(3.17)
 End If
 End If
 End Sub
```

but the above macro is working for only one screenshot. If want to resize all the selected images it needs some modification.

Kindly help me in modifying the macro.

Comment: Any suggestion will be of great helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I toke a look at this [tutorial](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/653-excel-delete-all-pictures.html) and i wrote that code :

```
 Sub ResizePics()
 Dim shp As Word.Shape
 Dim ishp As Word.InlineShape

For Each ishp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
 ishp.LockAspectRatio = False
 ishp.Height = InchesToPoints(1.78)
 ishp.Width = InchesToPoints(3.17)
Next ishp

For Each shp In ActiveDocument.Shapes
 shp.LockAspectRatio = False
 shp.Height = InchesToPoints(1.78)
 shp.Width = InchesToPoints(3.17)
Next shp
 End Sub
```

i am not a programmer, so this is just a try :)